# Uploading File in AWS S3 SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am making a webapp that communicates to AWS S3 SDK to upload files from my webapp to S3 Bucket. So far it worked like a charm but I have something I want to do. I want to group it in years like `2018` folder and `2019` folder.

If I will upload a file to S3 Bucket, it will be saved to a folder on what year it is being uploaded.

Does anyone know about it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 does not support folders/directories.

Instead, the filename ('Key') of each object includes the full path.

For example, you could upload a new object with a Key of:

```
2019/foo.txt
```

The object would 'appear' to be in a folder called `2019`, but it doesn't actually exist. If the object is deleted and there are no other objects in the `2019` folder, then the folder will disappear too.

Therefore, you can just upload objects to whatever location you wish, without having to actually create the directories.

Simply code your application to store the object with a Key that contains the full path.